# Tap area of UIButtons changes when in-call status bar is visible

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, in-call

**UPDATE 2**

My suspicious were correct. The problem was in the animations because I didn't took into consideration the  origin of the Y axis which was different when the in-call status bar was visible. I'll add an answer showing the relevant code as well.

**UPDATE 1**

I had a thought that the animation of the menu is causing the problem. When i press the menu, it start an animation to reveal the menu. The animation slides the presented VC to the right, shrink it just a bit and rotating it in the z axis to make it look smoothy cool.
I'll investigate in that direction and update if i'll find anything.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I noticed some UI problems while having the In-Call status bar visible in my app.

I have a custom view which acts as my navigation bar and contains a small button to go back to the menu. (I'll call it  `menuBtn`). Underneath this custom navigation bar I have table view containing a `tableViewHeader` with 2 buttons to navigate between days in the table. (I'll call those buttons: `prevBten` and `nextBtn`). I will use those 3 views as example but the problem accure all over...

Normally everything works perfect and as expected. Even when the In-Call status bar become visible, the resizing works perfect and life is great. The problem starts when I click `menuBtn` so the current view slides away to reveal the main menu (Doing so i switch between `Storyboards`). Now, when i'm going back to the original screen, all the views seems ok (size-wise) but the tap area now isn't matching the image of the buttons: I can see the button where it should be but when I tap it nothing happens. The weird part is that I can tap **underneath** the buttons and it will trigger the action bind to those buttons.

To make it even weirder - when the problem accure I can see that sometimes the tap area of a specific button (i.e `menuBtn`) **overlaps** a differnet button (`prevBtn`).

Been searching around for a while for the cause/solutions. I've read the following posts with no luck:

1. [`ClipToBounds` the parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108836/ios-button-tap-area-after-device-rotation).
2. [Play around with `AutoResizingMasks`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486491/how-in-call-status-bar-impacts-uiviewcontrollers-view-size-and-how-to-handle)

I got an hunch that its something to do with the fact i'm switching between `Storyboards` - though trying to set the autoresize in the interface builder didn't do the job.

**Some code that might help to anyone who might want to help**

The method that is triggered when the `menuBtn` is pressed:

```
- (void)replaceChildStoryboard:(NSString *)storyboardName
{
//remove previos child's view and itself from parent
[currNav removeFromParentViewController];
[currNav.view removeFromSuperview];

//instantiate new storyboard
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

//update curr pointer to new child and add it to parent
currNav = vc;
[self addChildViewController:currNav];
[self.view addSubview:currNav.view];
[currNav didMoveToParentViewController:self];

//animate transition
[self slideNavAnimated:NO];
[self navPressed];

}
```

**Some screenshots**

In the third screenshot, when I tap the `prevBtn` (the one underneath the `menuBtn`) I get the `menuBtn` action being activated instead. (as presented in the circles i draw - so tapping inside the red circle should activate the `prevBtn` but does trigger the `menuBtn`. tapping in the black circle should do nothing but does trigger the `prevBtn`)

[image: Normal state]
[image: In-Call status bar is open]
[image: tap area wrong]

Hope that someone can help me get to the root of the problem and fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the 2nd update of my question, the problem seems to be in the animation of the menu. Originally I didn't took into consideration the fact that the origin of the the view in the y-axis is different depends on the status of the in-call status bar (visible\invisible).

By adding the origin of the Y axis to the calculation of the animation, I fixed the problem.
So every call that looked like this:

```
 //adding the animations
      [currNav.view.layer addAnimation:[NRAnimationFactory positionAnimationFrom:CGPointMake(centerOriginX, self.view.frameHeight/2)
                                                                              To:CGPointMake(self.view.frameWidth, self.view.frameHeight/2)
                                                                        Duration:duration]
                                forKey:@"moving"];
```

I turn it into

```
 //adding the animations :
      [currNav.view.layer addAnimation:[NRAnimationFactory positionAnimationFrom:CGPointMake(centerOriginX, self.view.originY + self.view.frameHeight/2)
                                                                              To:CGPointMake(self.view.frameWidth, self.view.originY + self.view.frameHeight/2)
                                                                        Duration:duration]
                                forKey:@"moving"];
```

Note the additional `self.view.originY` which is equal to 0 when the in-call status bar is invisible, and 20 otherwise.

Hope this is going to help anyone. I wasted few days on it!